# Is there a better way to get the value of X after recursively multiplying by list Z?

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms

If I have a number **X** and a list of percentages **Z**, how would I find the value of **X** after repeatedly multiplying it (and its result) by each percentage value in the list **Z**?

**Naive Way:**

```
X = 100
Z = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.1]

for z in Z:
    X = X + (X * z)
```

Is there a better (faster) algorithm to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I translate your problem as:
\begin{align}
X_0 &= 100 \\
X_{i+1} &= X_i + X_i Z_i \quad \left( i \in \{0,\dotsc,N-1 \} \right)
\end{align}

There is little you can do if the $N$ percentages $Z_i$ have arbitrary values.

$$
X_{i+1} = X_i + X_i Z_i = X_i (1 + Z_i)
$$
which leads to
$$
X_N = X_0 \prod_{i=0}^{N-1}(1+Z_i)
$$